# Error when trying to do record set with string field, works with numbers

Tags: string, text, asp-classic, recordset

I'm trying to display a distinct set of values in a form.
When I use a number field all works fine.
When trying to use a string field, I get this error.

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'
Type mismatch: 'QRs(...)'
/RAY-QUICK.asp, line 92
```

```html
<option selected value="0"> - Ft_ProdCode - SQL tekst  </option>
```

```vb
<% ' -----------------------------------------------   START SQL QUERY
Set MyConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
MdbFilePath = Server.MapPath("/db/quickd.mdb") 
MyConn.Open "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=" & MdbFilePath & ";"

SQL_Query = "SELECT DISTINCT Quick.[Ft_ProdCode] FROM Quick;"

Set RS = MyConn.Execute(SQL_query) 
If Not Rs.EOF Then
    QRs = Rs.GetRows()
        QaantVelden = UBound(QRs):QaantRecords = UBound(QRs, 2)
Else
    AnaantRecords = -1
End If

Rs.Close
Set Rs = Nothing
myConn.Close
Set myConn = Nothing

DeCEL=0 : do while DeCEL<>Qaantrecords+1
    if QRS(0,deCEL )>0 then
        %>
        <option value="<%=QRS(0,deCEL )%>"><%=QRS(0,deCEL )%></option>
        <%  end if
    DeCEL=DeCEL+1 : loop : DeCEL=0

%>
```

```html
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing away with the array logic and just loop the rs instead:

```vb
Set MyConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
MdbFilePath = Server.MapPath("/db/quickd.mdb") 
MyConn.Open "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=" & MdbFilePath & ";"

Set RS = MyConn.Execute("SELECT DISTINCT Quick.[Ft_ProdCode] FROM Quick;") 

do while not RS.eof
    response.write("<option value=""" & RS("Ft_ProdCode") & """>" & RS("Ft_ProdCode") & "</option>")
    RS.movenext
loop

Rs.Close
Set Rs = Nothing
myConn.Close
Set myConn = Nothing
```

Comment: Don't encourage this the `ADODB.Recordset` object is a blimp as it is, `GetRows()` and `Close()` should be the most used methods when working with `ADODB.Recordset` unless you want to do something 99.89% of people don't.

Comment: It's pointless helping when people just want a "quick fix". Good luck when you actually try this with a SQL Server and million or so records.

Comment: He's outputting a few <option> tags & clearly won’t be looping a million or so records in this instance - both will execute < 1ms. If you want to help him preserve array use feel free to post an answer of your own & stop nitpicking.